# How do you center a statement and italicise it without making it a theorem?

Tags: spacing, numbering, positioning, italic

I want to have a statement in my proof with an implication sign in it, I want it centred and italicised and I want it numbered. (1)
How do you do this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{ dsfont } 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\textit{Als X een overaftelbare deelverzameling van $\mathds{R}$ is, dan is er een bijectie van X naar $\mathds{R}$.$\implies$ it is day time.}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please show us a compilable code that we can play with ...

Comment: One way would be to use an `equation` environment: `\begin{equation}\textit{It is sunny $\implies$ it is day time.}\end{equation}`.  But, It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  That way a solution that works for your particular case could e presented.

Comment: your question isn't very clear, in particular _which_ number do you want (for example equation counter or a specific number sequence for implications)? Also why do you not want to make it a theorem? theroem environemnts don't have to be mathematical theorems, they are often used for remarks or notes or proofs or...a `theorem` to latex is just a kind of numbered set off paragraph display. Just as a `list` does not need to be a real list (for example `center` and `environment` are `list` as far as their latex implementation goes).

Comment: @PeterGrill this is what I needed but when I do this, it doesn't automatically make a new line. How do I solve this?

Comment: @RolWezel: It makes a new line for me. I'd suggest you edit the question and add a composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. Not sure how to help you further without it.

Comment: @PeterGrill I'm using \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}. I think you got me wrong. It does add a new line after the full statement, but my statement between the {} is too long,  so it doesn't fit on one line.

Comment: @RolWezel: Instead of describing the problem, can you just please edit the question and post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill Is this what you mean?

Comment: Note that you can format code as code by indenting 4 spaces (easy way: highlight and press '{}' button).

Comment: Note that `equation` puts you in maths mode. So you don't need `$` to enter maths mode in that environment. (Unless you are using e.g. `\parbox` as in Peter Grill's solution.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few options:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\parbox{0.7\linewidth}{ Als X een overaftelbare deelverzameling van $\mathds{R}$ is, dan is er een bijectie van X naar $\mathds{R}$.
$\implies$ 
it is day time.}
\end{equation}
Alternatively you can use:
\begin{equation}
\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{Als X een overaftelbare deelverzameling van $\mathds{R}$ is, dan is er een bijectie van X naar $\mathds{R}$. }
\Bigg\}\implies 
\parbox{0.2\linewidth}{it is day time.}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).